# Input type search in Menu

Tags: php, menus, filters, search

Hi as a noob I want to achieve the following. I want to bring a search input field into a registered menu. Therefore I read a wpbeginner.com tutorial, which is basically following an aproach with a filter hook.

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_search_box_to_menu', 10, 2);
function add_search_box_to_menu( $items, $args ) {
    if( $args->theme_location == 'primary' ){
        return $items."<li class='menu-header-search'><form action='http://example.com/' id='searchform' method='get'><input type='text' name='s' id='s' placeholder='Search'></form></li>";
        }
    return $items;
}
```

So this seems to become the first filter hook in my life. In order to achive an html output, which is similar to the "search-widget" output I come to this solution and in my beginners opinion it seems to be an example for worse coding.

```
function add_search_box_to_menu($items, $args) {
        if ($args->theme_location == 'menu-1') {
            return $items . "<li class='search-field'>"
                    . "<form action='"
                    . esc_url(home_url())
                    . "' id='searchform'"
                    . " method='get'"
                    . "role ='search'>"
                    . "<label>"
                    . "<span class='screen-reader-text'>" 
                    . esc_html__('Search for:', 'bloook')
                    . "</span>"
                    . "<input type='search' name='s' id='s' "
                    . "placeholder='" 
                    . esc_html__('Search', 'bloook') 
                    . "'>" 
                    . "</label>"
                    . "<input class='search-submit' value ='"
                    . esc_html__('Search', 'bloook')
                    . "' type='submit'>"
                    . "</form></li>";
        }
        return $items;
    }
    add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_search_box_to_menu', 10, 2);
```

Although it seems to be working... . Here are my questions:

As a (PHP,WP & English) noob I am wondering, if there is a more maintainable or clearer way of achiving my goal?

Or... Am I only self irritated by my low level php skills? Or does it look like normal code for you?

Where is a good place for a filter hook like this (actually its placed in my functions.php directly under the registration of navigation)?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fine, but you if you want things to look "cleaner" and be easier to modify you could instead create a new file menu-search.php and add your HTML there then tweak your function a bit (don't forget to prefix your functions)

```
function myprefix_add_search_box_to_menu($items, $args) {
if ( $args->theme_location == 'menu-1' ) {
    ob_start();
    get_template_part( 'menu-search' );
    $items .= ob_get_clean();
}
return $items;
```

}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'myprefix_add_search_box_to_menu', 10, 2);

Comment: Thank you very much, this looks a lot cleaner than my approach. I will study the things that are new to me and try it out. Meanwhile many thanks for your suggestion and the new direction.

Comment: After get a little deeper into the materia.  Hats off and respect. Although now I am wondering if the hack with output buffering for saving the get_template_part is fine for performance? Might worth a further question? Once more many many thanks @WPExplorer.